# Unable to import createRefs() for constraint layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

[My Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRn4F.png)

[Its asking me to import Focus request but i want to use the createRef() for Constraint layout reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3er6y.png)

I'm using this version: "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-rc01"

Comment: Move line 27 into constraintLayout resolve problem, it should be put below line 33

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's too late but I got the same problem and found the answer.

I forgot to surround createRefs by ConstraintLayout. It should be like this.

```
ConstraintLayout {
  val (button, text) = createRefs()

  Button(
    onClick = { /* Do something */ },
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(button) {
      top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = 16.dp)
    }
  ) {
    Text("Button")
  }

  Text("Text", Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
    top.linkTo(button.bottom, margin = 16.dp)
  })
}
```

and you should import this.

```
import androidx.constraintlayout.compose.ConstraintLayout
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

When you want to write your "ConstraintSet" be careful not to add any other implementation of "androidx.compose